# Texture is being deleted?

Tags: c++, sfml, imgui

```cpp
// Sprite.
if(ImGui::CollapsingHeader("Sprite.")) {
    // Preview texture allocations.
    sf::Texture texture;

    // ...

    static char spritePath[MAX_OBJECTS_TEXT_SIZE / 2]; // (512 / 2)

    // ...

    if(ImGui::InputText("Sprite path.##sprite", spritePath, IM_ARRAYSIZE(spritePath))) {
        texture.loadFromFile(spritePath);
    }

    // ...

    // Preview. (150, 150).
    ImGui::Image(texture, sf::Vector2f(DEFAULT_TEXTURE_PREVIEW_WIDTH, DEFAULT_TEXTURE_PREVIEW_HEIGHT), sf::Color::Transparent, sf::Color::White);
}
```

Result:
[image]

example.png - exactly exists and there are no errors (that the texture cannot be loaded).

From SFML documentation -

> You've successfully loaded the texture, built the sprite correctly, and... now all you see on your screen is a white square. What happened?
>
> It's a common mistake. When you set a sprite texture, all it internally does is store a pointer to an instance of the texture. So if the texture is destroyed or moved to another location in memory, the sprite ends up with an invalid texture pointer.

```cpp
sf::Sprite loadSprite(std::string filename)
{
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile(filename);

    return sf::Sprite(texture);
} // error: the texture is destroyed here
```

`
I don't understand why the texture is destroyed if I created it in one if block and how to make it not destroyed?

P.S: ImGui::Image function - draws the image in the next frame, and in the next frame the texture is deleted, how do I make infinite lifetime for texture?

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
sf::Texture texture;
texture.loadFromFile(filename);

return sf::Sprite(texture);
```

The `texture` is a local variable that ceases to exist at the end of the function (or scope) it is in (basically, once you hit the `}`). Thus the sprite is holding on to a pointer (or reference) to a deleted object.

You need to either load the texture in a scope where it outlives the sprite or allocate it using dynamic (heap) memory.